# Was Chaitanya Mahaprabhu really against Adi Shankaracharya 's teachings?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, chaitanya-charitamrita, chaitanya-bhagavata, iskcon

Modern-day followers of Chaitanya (Krishna avatar) Mahaprabhu like ISCKON says that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was against Adi Shankara's (Shiva avatar) teaching, but if we see the life of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu we come to know that he comes under dashanami sampradaya. There were other dualistic schools at that time. If Chaitanya Mahaprabhu really wanted to oppose Adi Shankara, then why didn't he take diksha from those school?
How can a shishya oppose his guru?
And how can Krishna oppose Shiva?

Comment: Being a sannyasi of the Dashanami order doesn't means that you can't oppose Adi Shankaracharya. Madhvacharya was initiated into sannyasa of the Tirtha subgroup of Dashanami order with the the monastic name of Ananda Tirtha by an Advaitin named Achutyapreksha Tirtha before he was initiated into Krishna mantra by Vyasadeva. Even Sri Chaitanya's paramaguru Madhavendra Puri was also in the Dashanami order. Besides the anti-Advaitins view Shiva to be inferior to Vishnu & Adi Shankara to be a pracchanna-Bauddha. Gaudiyas also believe that Sandipani Muni had incarnated as Chaitanya's sannyasa guru.

Comment: @Anubrata Bit At the time of Madhvacharya there were no other vedantic sects other than advaita and vishistadvaita. Most of the sanyasis of Karnataka were advaitians. So according to me, at the time of Madhvacharya there were no options. Moreover bhavishya puran,pratisarga parva,khand 4,chapter 19(1&2)declares Chaitanya Mahaprabhu as smartha not gaudiya vaishnava.                   If I accept your thought then what about Krishna (!Chaitanya Mahaprabhu)disagreeing with Shiva(Adi Shankaracharya).

Comment: In this regard, all anti-Advaitins quote a verse from Padma Purana in which Shiva tells Parvati that he would incarnate on earth as a Brahmin & spread a crypto-Buddhist doctrine called Mayavada in order to deliberately lead men away from the Vaidik fold into hell. Other texts decry Adi Shankara further by stating him to be an incarnation of an Asura named Maniman. And since they unanimously believe that Vishnu is the only Paramatman, they don't find Vishnu refuting Shiva (who their view as an extraordinarily powerful jivatman but not on par with Vishnu who is the Paramatman) to be unnatural.

Comment: If you doubt modern-day followers like ISKCON, then you should go to their roots (i.e. hagiographies and the writings of associates). For example, there are many verses in the Chaitanya Charitamrita that speak against the Advaita doctrine.

Comment: @MassEnquirer Chaitanya charitam wasn't written by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. Someone may have misunderstood it. According to me Chaitanya Mahaprabhu didn't learn advaita from a scholar whose anthakarana was pure,so he may be opposing advaita which he heard. I think the problem is with the people who think that they have understood advaita but they are with impure anthakaran. In bhavishya puran Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says "Krishna is not ultimate god". U can check it in Bhavishya puran Pratisarga Parva,khand 4, 19.1 and 19.2 in which he declares himself belonging to smartha tradition.

Comment: @ShripadRJoshi Dwaitis and Vishishtadwaitis are also Smartas. Anyone who follows Smrutis and Shruthi is a Smarta. It's like Pandavas and Kauravas. Pandavas are also Kauravas. So Smartha doesn't technically mean Advaiti. Also Chaitanya Mahaprabhu took initiation from a Dvaita schola

Comment: wasn't Madhvacharya suggesting dvaita? and wasn't adi shankara advaita? and wasn't chaitanya's philosohpy more closely aligned with dvaita?